# How do I represent uint8 literals in Java

Tags: java, sha, primitive, libsodium

I am trying to re-implement some code that uses libsodium in Java.
The original code declares an array of type uint8:

```
#define SECRET ((uint8_t[]){ 0xAA, 0xBB, 0xCC ... }) // not the real secret!
```

and feeds that to libsodium's `crypto_hash_sha256_update`

My challenge in implementing this in Java is that Java has no unsigned bytes, so I can't actually type `0xAA` as a byte.

Things I've tried:

- Declaring my array as short/int: I think this breaks because of 0 padding
- Declaring the literals as `0b11110000...` format, this doesn't give the right answers (I have some test data from the original implementation)
- Declaring an array of `char []` and concatenating the literals: final char[] salt = { 0xAABB, 0xCCDD, ...}`, doesn't give right answers either

EDIT
this is my short attempt

```
    final short[] salt = { 0xAA, 0xBB, ...};


    final Hasher hasher = Hashing.sha256().newHasher();
    hasher.putLong(input);
    for (int i=0; i < salt.length; i++) {
        hasher.putShort(salt[i]);
    }
    return hasher.hash().asBytes();
```

Comment: It's impossible why the sensible idea of using `short` isn't working without seeing the code you wrote, which is clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: you can type `(byte)0xaa`, but you should use them properly too, for example cast to int before shifting, ie `((int)byteVar)<<8`

Comment: editting with short attempt

Comment: You can type `(byte) 0xAA`, and there's not actually that much difference between signed and unsigned bytes.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I tried (byte) again and it worked, looks like I forgot about left padding the result

Comment: @benhsu Then consider adding a reasonably detailed answer for your own question and marking it as accepted after you've thoroughly confirmed it resolves the issue as you expected it to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my original code worked

```
final short[] salt = { 0xAA, 0xBB, ...};


final Hasher hasher = Hashing.sha256().newHasher();
hasher.putLong(input);
for (int i=0; i < salt.length; i++) {
    hasher.putShort(salt[i]);
}
return hasher.hash().asBytes();
```

The problem was I forgot to left-pad my result before comparing